# assertion in first order logic

Tags: logic

Can anybody give me  an idea how to write this assertion in in first order logic?

> X has not passed one or more of the prerequisites for A.

Here, X is the name of a person and A is a constant representing a course name.

Comment: You could have a prerequisite object type and a predicate P(a, b, c) - person 'a' passed a prerequisite 'b' for course 'c'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expressing properties of elements of the universe in first order logic is mostly achieved through defining appropriate relations. So for this you might like to consider relations like:

- $P(x)$ - $x$ is a person,
- $C(x)$ - $x$ is a course,
- $Pre(x,y)$ - $x$ is a prerequisite of $y$ (note that this doesn't actually say that $x$ and $y$ are courses),
- $Pass(x,y)$ - $x$ has passed course $y$.

(The parentheses are just included for clarity - you may have seen different notation where relations are written without.)

Then the rest is just building the logical formula, which in this case should be fairly obvious.

> $notready(x,a) \equiv P(x) \wedge C(a) \wedge \exists y(C(y) \wedge Pre(y,a) \wedge \neg Pass(x,y)) $